# How to select max item in each group?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregation-framework

The collection is like below:

```
Name      Subject    Score
Li        Math       89
Wang      Math       97
Su        Math       85
Li        History    80
Wang      History    73
Su        History    75
Li        Science    90
Wang      Science    83
Su        Science    65
```

I want to get the highest subject for everyone, result like:

```
Li        Science    90
Wang      Math       97
Su        Math       85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
db.scores.aggregate(  { $group: {
     _id: { name: "$name", subject: "$subject" },
     'maxscore': { $max : "$score" }
}})
```